# Code not Inserting the Event into the Calendar

Tags: android, events, insert, calendar

Does anyone see why this code is not inserting the event into the calendar? I have no errors, it just doesn't insert the event?

I'm using the galaxy s2 with the ICS update, not sure if this is relevant but just wondering if it has something to do with it not being the Google calendar app.

```
public void addEvent(Context ctx, String title, Calendar start, Calendar end) {
   Log.d(TAG, "AddUsingContentProvider.addEvent()");

TextView calendarList = 
    (TextView) ((Activity) ctx).findViewById(R.id.calendarList);

ContentResolver contentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();

ContentValues calEvent = new ContentValues();
calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1); // XXX pick)
calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, start.getTimeInMillis());
calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, end.getTimeInMillis());
calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "Canada/Eastern");
Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, calEvent);

// The returned Uri contains the content-retriever URI for 
// the newly-inserted event, including its id
int id = Integer.parseInt(uri.getLastPathSegment());
Toast.makeText(ctx, "Created Calendar Event " + id,
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead of "Canada/Eastern" , timeZone.getID() like this:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
```

Also check when you look for the event,because some java calendar/date functions have 0-indexed month.So you set the month 11 is december not november.Just in case..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is solved. Tried the following code and it is working on 4.0
Watch out the Month is 0 based so the 2103, 12, resolved to 2014, Jan, 20
{

```
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();//it puts in 2014, Jan 20
    beginTime.set(2013, 12, 20, 7, 30);
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(2013, 12, 20, 8, 30);

    ContentValues calEvent = new ContentValues();
    calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1); // XXX pick)
    calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "title is game time");
    calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, beginTime.getTimeInMillis());
    calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endTime.getTimeInMillis());
    calEvent.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    Uri uri = this.getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, calEvent);

    // The returned Uri contains the content-retriever URI for 
    // the newly-inserted event, including its id
    int id = Integer.parseInt(uri.getLastPathSegment());
    Toast.makeText(this, "Created Calendar Event " + id,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
calEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE);
```

works like a charm!